Scroll continuously while condition is true using React Native's ScrollView
I'm currently implementing a drag-and-drop list using react-native-gesture-handler. The list is implemented as a simple Array.map() within a ScrollView since a FlatList would be incompatible with some other UI structures used in the app.
I've got the drag-and-drop functionality working but am struggling with the last requirement, which is auto-scrolling the ScrollView when the user drags an item to the top or bottom screen edge. Basically, I'm looking for a way to do this:
while (someCondition) {
  scrollViewRef.current.slowlyScrollDown();
}

I've tried to do something like this:
const handleDrag = useCallback((absoluteY) => {
  const scrollThreshold = 100; // pixels from top/bottom to trigger scroll

  if (autoScrollTimerRef.current) {
    clearInterval(autoScrollTimerRef.current);
  }

  if (absoluteY < scrollThreshold) {
    // Scroll up
    const newOffset = currentScrollOffset - 10;
    autoScrollTimerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      containerRef.current?.scrollTo({y: newOffset, animated: true});
    }, 1000 / 60);
    setCurrentScrollOffset(newOffset);
  } else if (absoluteY > screenHeight - scrollThreshold) {
    // Scroll down
    const newOffset = currentScrollOffset + 10;
    autoScrollTimerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      containerRef.current?.scrollTo({y: newOffset, animated: true});
    }, 1000 / 60);
    setCurrentScrollOffset(newOffset);
  }
}, []);

However, this is extremely janky and, in general, not a pleasant experience. I suppose this is because the previous scroll animation didn't complete when the next animation cycle started.
Is there any better way to do this?
